# String array initialization using for loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

I have a listView which displays list of recent files in android app. Here, I have a File array "fileList[]" and its length sizeOfFiles. I am assigning names of files to the string array "file_names" and then putting this string in ArrayAdapter to be used in listView.
Is there any way to assign values to string using for loop? I tried it using for loop but my application stopped working.
So I used multiple else if statements.

```
String file_names[]= null;
        if (sizeOfFiles < 1) {
            file_names = new String[]{"No recent files.\nTouch New to add files."};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.file_list, file_names);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        else if (sizeOfFiles == 1) {
            file_names = new String[]{filesList[sizeOfFiles - 1].getName()};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.file_list, file_names);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        else if (sizeOfFiles == 2) {
            file_names = new String[]{filesList[sizeOfFiles - 1].getName(), filesList[sizeOfFiles - 2].getName()};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.file_list, file_names);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: code totally unreadable ":what is authors goal" Maybe show previous version with loop?

Comment: Actually I have a listView which displays list of recent files in android app. Here, I have a File array "fileList[]" and its length sizeOfFiles. I am assigning names of files to the string array "file_names" and then putting this string in ArrayAdapter to be used in listView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood you are searching for something like that:

```
        String file_names[]= new String[(int)Math.max(sizeOfFiles,1)];
        if (sizeOfFiles < 1) {
            file_names[0] = "No recent files.\nTouch New to add files.";
        } else  { 
            for(int i=sizeOfFiles-1;i>=0;i--){
                file_names[(sizeOfFiles-1)-i] = filesList[i].getName();
            }
        }  
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.file_list, file_names);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! It is what I was looking for.